# Инициализация вектора в конструкторе

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация

```
class A {
public:
 A(size_t size):vector(size, default_value){}

private:
 std::vector<int> vector;
 const int default_value = -1;
}
```

Почему вектор инициализируется рандомным значением? Константа ещё не успевает стать `-1`? Как тогда сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Да, раз Вы проводите инициализацию в списке инициализации, то надо строчку с константой вынести выше, поскольку операция конструирования полей класса происходит в порядке из записи. У Вас еще неизвестно значение этой константы. Поэтому сделайте минимум так:

```
class A 
{
public:
A(size_t size)
    : vector(size, default_value) {}

private:
сonst int default_value = -1;
std::vector<int> vector;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Члены класса инициализируются в порядке их объявления в классе. Поэтому для этого определения класса

```
class A {
public:
 A(size_t size):vector(size, default_value){}

private:
 std::vector<int> vector;
 const int default_value = -1;
};
```

член данных `vector` инициализируется, когда член данных `default_value` еще не был инициализирован.

Если переставить эти члены данных местами, то программа будет иметь ожидаемое поведение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A 
{
public:
    A( size_t size ) : vector( size, default_value ) { }
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const A & );

private:

    const int default_value = -1;
    std::vector<int> vector;
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A &a )
{
    for ( int x : a.vector ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    return os;
}


int main() 
{
    A a( 10 );

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Из стандарта C++ (12.6.2 Initializing bases and members)

> 13 In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order:

...

> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were 
>     declared in the class deﬁnition (again regardless of the order of the
>     mem-initializers).

Если бы вы объявили член данных `default_value` как статический член данных класса, то тогда инициализация нестатического члена данных `vector` не зависела бы от порялка объявления этих членов данных, так как статические члены класса инициализируются до создания любого объекта класса.

```
class A 
{
public:
    A( size_t size ) : vector( size, default_value ) { }
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const A & );

private:

    std::vector<int> vector;
    static const int default_value = -1;
};
```